# debug toolbar not visible in symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm new to Symfony and in my company, I take over the project created by someone else using Symfony 1.4 & is not available now.

I went through jobeet tutorial and mostly comfortable with symfony but I could not load debug toolbar even environment is set to 'dev'. Debug bar is not visible even through frontend_dev.php file. Common settings are:

**factories.yml**

```
prod:
    logger:
        class:   sfNoLogger
        param:
            level:   err
            loggers: ~

dev:
    mailer:
        param:
          delivery_strategy: none
```

**Settings.yml**

```
prod:
  .settings:
    error_reporting:        <?php echo ((E_ALL | E_STRICT))."\n" ?>
    no_script_name:         true
    logging_enabled:        true

dev:
  .settings:
    error_reporting:        <?php echo (((E_ALL | E_STRICT)^ E_NOTICE) ^ E_DEPRECATED)."\n" ?>
    web_debug:              true
    cache:                  false
    no_script_name:         false
    etag:                   false
    compressed:             false
```

**Frontend_dev.php** file include

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');

$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'dev', true);
sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();
```

Where is the error? We are using custom design defined in layout, partials and template (*Success.php) pages. Do I need to add some code to layout to enable debug bar?

Comment: Does the c/p of `settings.yml` is good? Because you have a one space indented instead of 2 for `.settings` (which can cause the problem you've got)

Comment: Yes I cross-checked setting.yml file again. 'Two space' are used everywhere including in 'dev:' settings. One space shown here is mistake here, while pasting text.

Comment: Thanks J,

That was the reason. I changed web_debug:true but didn't cleared the cache since last few days. It started working as soon as I cleared cache.

Comment: Common symfony rules: if something doesn't change after updated one configuration file: `php symfony cc`

Comment: Yes, after this incident, I'll keep that as first debug thing.

However, there is another problem now. Debug bar not opening. On web console, I'm getting following message:

ReferenceError: sfWebDebugShowDetailsFor is not defined

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Does icon are well displayed in your toolbar? I mean, a real image not a not found image.

Comment: Yes, images are proper. However that problem is appearing only on single page which have heavy use of javascript/jquery. I guess there might be some JS conflict. I guess I should be able fix it easily as problem seems with my custom javascripts.

Thanks for wonderful and timely support.

Please add your third comment as answer so that I can accept that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you clear your cache?

Common symfony rules (kind of *#protips*):

> if something doesn't change after updated one configuration file, try: **`php symfony cc`**

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your httpd.conf (for apache web server) file particularly your virtual host definition. Add this
Alias /sf /home/sfproject/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf

AllowOverride All
Allow from All

See [this](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/03-Running-Symfony#chapter_03_sub_the_secure_way).